# Terminal smart-device use in Visual Studio 2017 (Windows CE)

Tags: visual-studio-2017, smart-device

I need to develop in visual studio 2017 for terminals (Windows CE).

Mainly the terminal I want to develop to is ZEBRA MC9190 based on windows ce.

I see solution in: [SmartDevice in Visual Studio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fRgXH_-5EHE&t=22s), but this is not appropiate to the visual studio 2017 (Since I cannot see smart device project type on the list of available projects, when I create a new project).

The best installation I could see is 'mobile development with .NET', but even install that feature, I cannot understand how to add a smartdevice project.

Please, help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Visual Studio 2008. It can be installed side-by-side to VS2017. The best way to get it is a MSDN Subscription.